# Pasteboard - copying (image) creates mystery \n line break in custom keyboard

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, uipasteboard

When I add an image to the pasteboard I get a  line break at the end of my image?

its my code

```
 UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
 NSData *data= UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"]);
            [pasteboard setData:data forPasteboardType:@"public.png"];
```

this code successfully paste image from `Pasteboard`, but image come with extra line break(after next to image). 
If I just copy the text it does not add a mysterious line-break.

if can anyone think of some nice solution then please share with me.
Thanks in advance.....